# convert 32bpp Bitmap to 16bpp (Grayscale)

Tags: c#, bitmap, pixel

I'm creating a Bitmap in C# from an Image object.

The Bitmap I get is 32bpp, how can I transform that to 16bpp?

```
Bitmap image_bmp;
System.Drawing.Image tmp = (System.Drawing.Image)img.RenderImage(0); //RenderImage creates an object of tyoe System.Drawing.Image
image_bmp = new Bitmap(tmp);
```

Comment: 16bpp ...grayscale? color? You'll need to be a bit more specific on what format you want! : )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you run a quick search on google you can find a number of excellent color to grayscale formulas. Take the following [from wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grayscale) as an example:

```
Y' =  0.2126 R' + 0.7152 G' + 0.0722 B'
```

With this in mind the general process in .NET is going to be:

- Create a new image of the correct dimensions with 16bpp grayscale
- Use "LockBits" on the original image and the new image and loop over each pixel
- Unlock both images, then save the new image to a file

Rather than going into these steps further I found a few other questions from stack and around the web that really delve into the details more. See:

- [Set individual pixels in .NET Format16bppGrayScale image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3474434/set-individual-pixels-in-net-format16bppgrayscale-image)
- [How to convert pixel formats? From 32bppRGB to 16bpp grayscale in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6251599/how-to-convert-pixel-formats-from-32bpprgb-to-16bpp-grayscale-in-c-sharp)
- http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/10252c05-c4b6-49dc-b2a3-4c1396e2c3ab/writing-a-16bit-grayscale-image?forum=csharpgeneral

Best of luck!

**NOTE** - I'm assuming your using GDI+. The steps are is similar for Windows Imaging Component (WIC) but the classes and syntax is radically different.